# Javascript:missing ) after argument error on returning a button

Tags: javascript, virtual-dom

I am trying to return a button in some function on UI and get a wierd error. Can someone please help.

```
var div = "<button onclick='javascript:displayDetails('+value1+','+value2+');'>View</button>"
```

Error i get is:

missing ) after argument list.

Comment: When do you get the error?

Comment: Try this: `var div = "<button onclick=\"javascript:displayDetails('"+value1+"','"+value2+"');\">View</button>"`

Comment: WTH are you trying to do? Do you really want to pass the strings `'+value1+'` and `'+value2+'` to `displayDetails(…)`?

Comment: Just don't use inline event handler attributes at all, but proper DOM listeners

Comment: Thank u @mrlew it worked.

Comment: @fiddle you're welcome

Answer (score 1):

```
 onclick="javascript:displayDetails('+value1+','+value2+');"
```

Not

```
 onclick='javascript:displayDetails('+value1+','+value2+');'
```

---

Use `` which supports multiple lines instead of '' and to avoid nested "":

```
const div = `
   <button onclick="javascript:displayDetails('+value1+','+value2+');">
       View
   </button>`;
```

Not

```
const div = "<button onclick='javascript:displayDetails('+value1+','+value2+');'>View</button>"
```

Then you will not need to espace

Answer (score 0):

You should escape:

```
var div = "<button onclick=\"javascript:displayDetails('+value1+','+value2+');\">View</button>"
```

Comment: after this i get: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } at line 2 which is a blank line

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of JavaScript (ES2015, formerly/also known as ES6) now supports "template strings" that can help avoid just this kind of quoting/escaping nightmare. Use the "backtick quote" (aka grave accent) around the string to signal a template string, and a template syntax of `${value}` for each value you want "interpolated" (included) into the string:

```
var div = `<button onclick="javascript:displayDetails(${value1},${value2});">View</button>`;
```

In general, it's best to choose a standard for which quote marks you're going to use when. Many modern JavaScript style guides prefer single quotes (`'`) for normal strings, and double quotes (`"`) for surrounding HTML (or XML) attributes. Now having a third quotation mechanism means you don't have to backslash-escape quote marks so often--nice, because escaping is annoying, error-prone, and anti-clarity.